# Skip gradle test with aws sam build

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-serverless

I have java spring boot gradle project. When I use `sam build` command it fails because of failing tests. Is there a way to skip tests with sam build.

I know that tests can be skipped with `gradle build` like so: `gradle build -x test` but don't know how to supply such options to `sam build` command.

Comment: Does anybody find a solution?

Comment: This is the only way I've found. https://roamingthings.de/posts/disable-gradle-tests-on-sam-build/